# Split a comma separated string of double values into a double array in Java8

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a String containing double values such as:

```
String str = "0.1,0.4,0.9,0.1";
```

I want to get a double array from this string like this:

```
double[] arr = {0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 0.1};
```

The most obvious way to do this for me is:

```
String[] tokens = str.split(",");
double[] arr = new double[tokens.length];
int i=0
for (String st : tokens) {
    arr[i++] = Double.valueOf(st);
}
```

is there some faster/better way to do that other than the one mentioned above in Java 8?

Comment: 'Better"?  Depends on how you define "better".  "Faster"?  Probably not.

Comment: hmm, maybe not necessarily faster.. essentially what I was looking for was a more efficient way to do this in Java8 using stream.. as Eran has mentioned in answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Stream`s:

```
double[] arr = Stream.of(str.split(","))
                     .mapToDouble (Double::parseDouble)
                     .toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for